# Distplot 'a' parameter, does not make logical sense to me, can anyone explain?

Tags: visualization, matplotlib, beginner, seaborn, parameter

Most sns plot parameters have names that make somewhat logical sense,
For example scatterplot has the x attribute to choose what to plot on the x-axis, and y for y-axis. Similarly kdeplot uses the parameter data.

But as far as I can see, distplot uses the parameter 'a' and only that to specify what data to plot (I tried substituting 'a' for 'data' but that gave me an error)

Could someone tell my why was this choice made for the parameter name, as this seems very illogical from where I stand, and has forced me to correct my code more than a few times.

Comment: only the original developers can answer this question authenticaly. A plausible reason is that `a` is the start letter of `array`